# Visa for China: leisure and work

Tags: china

I am a European citizen and I will be attending an academic conference in China. However, after the conference I would like to travel a bit (say 10 days). The conference organisers are providing an invitation letter but this only states the duration of the conference. Can I add leisure to this trip when applying for a visa?

I also read [the following](https://freechinavisa.org/china-visa-faq/what-is-the-difference-between-a-tourist-visa-and-a-business-visa.html):

*However, there is no distinctive line between tourist visa and business visa. In another word, tourist visa will not prevent you from conducting business in China.*

So would it be better to simply apply for a tourist visa?